# How to check for missing @Override annotations with Maven

Tags: java, annotations, javac, maven-compiler-plugin

I've a maven project in which, I'm sure, there are classes which need and don't have `@Override` annotations. Is there a way to configure maven compiler plugin to show a warning on missing `@Override` annotations?

I'm using Netbeans but I would prefer to do it with maven only

Comment: If you are looking for a Maven-based solution, I would recommend you remove the references to Netbeans in your title and question.

Answer (score 1):

In Netbeans click on Source > Inspect. Then you can set the "search scope" (project, current file..). When you click on the "Manage" Button you can uncollapse "JDK 1.5 and later" where you can check the box "Add `@Override` Annotation. This helps you finding the missing `@Override` Annotations.

But i can't tell you how to find the needless `@Override` Annotations..

With maven you can try to add these lines to the maven compiler plugin config (didn't try this at all..):

```
<compilerArgs>
   <arg>-Xlint:rawtypes</arg>
   <arg>-Xlint:overrides</arg>
</compilerArgs>
```

Comment: thank you very much, unfortunately I need also a maven compiler plugin configuration to do so :(

Comment: ` <arg>-Xlint:overrides</arg>` doesn't work because semantics of this command of javac is not to check for missing @Override annotations but  on type of parameters of functions also annotated with @Override!